# What is the alternative for es.mapping.timestamp in ElasticSearch 7.x?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, elastic-stack, elk

The official documentation for ElasticSearch says:

> The document field/property name containing the document timestamp. To specify a constant, use the  format. Will not work on Elasticsearch 6.0+ index versions, but support will continue for 5.x index versions and below.

And accordingly, when I try to use it to make sure that my indices have timestamp separately, I get this error.

> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot use timestamps on index/update requests in ES 6.x and above. Please remove the [es.mapping.timestamp] setting.

The code I tried is:

df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").config("es.mapping.timestamp","timestamp")mode("overwrite").save("indexname/doc")

timestamp is a field in the Spark dataframe. I have tried it with saveToEs as well and got the same error. Is there any way I can do this in ElasticSearch 7.x by using any other field?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar w/ Spark but the `_timestamp` meta field is deprecated so you'll have to use a [`date` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) which'd be defined in the ES mapping -- depending on your spec its format could either be `epoch_second` or `epoch_millis`:

```
PUT your_index_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_second"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After that, I suppose you wouldn't need `.config("es.mapping.timestamp","timestamp")` anymore because the `timestamp` values in your docs would be directly parsed in ES as `date` fields supporting their respective date queries.

Comment: Thanks for this. So there is no way to specify it directly from my code which is generating the data? I would have to go through this API

Comment: Well you'd set this mapping once and only once. The question is whether you're moving to 7.x in the sense that you're starting fresh & reindexing everything?